# Udp how to get integer from the server?

Tags: java, sockets, udp

i shall implement a UDP-based client/server application and im new in the world of Java. The Server implements a simple request-acknowledge protocol upon the UDP protocol. For a received string identifier (command) with optional parameters the server returns a specified result. For example "thread" returns a random integer number between 1 and 5 and length returns a random integer number between 5 and 25.

The questions is did i do the implementation right and how can i fix my problem (length nr is always between 1 and 5). I think my problem is that in the server class the if statements are not checked. Is there some other way to send a comand to a server i tried here to do it with sending strings then trying to check it with if statements?

and thats my code (Server):

```
public class server {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException  {

    DatagramSocket skt;
    try {
        skt = new DatagramSocket(1252);

       byte [] buffer = new byte[1000];

        while(true){
            DatagramPacket request = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
            skt.receive(request);
            String arrayMsg = new String(request.getData());
            System.out.println(arrayMsg);

            //check if the client asks for threadnr
            if(arrayMsg.equals("thread")){
            int threadnumber = (int) (Math.random()*5)+1;
            String threadnum  = Integer.toString(threadnumber);
            byte [] b = threadnum.getBytes();
            DatagramPacket reply = new DatagramPacket(b, b.length, request.getAddress(), request.getPort());
            skt.send(reply);;}

            //check if the client asks for lengthnr
            else if(arrayMsg.equals("length")){
            int lengthnumber = (int) (Math.random()*25)+5;
            String lengthnum = Integer.toString(lengthnumber);
            byte [] b = lengthnum.getBytes();
            DatagramPacket reply = new DatagramPacket(b,  b.length,request.getAddress(), request.getPort());
            skt.send(reply);}           
    }}
    catch (SocketException e) {
        System.out.println("UDP Port 9876 is occupied.");
        System.exit(1);
    }}}
```

thats my Client:

```
public class client {

public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {

    DatagramSocket skt = new DatagramSocket();
    InetAddress host = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");
    int serverSocket = 1252;
    byte [] senddata = new byte [1000];
    byte [] getdata = new byte[1000];

    //thread send request
    String th = "thread";
    senddata = th.getBytes();
    DatagramPacket requestth = new DatagramPacket(senddata, senddata.length, host, serverSocket);
    skt.send(requestth);

    //thread get reply
    DatagramPacket replyth = new DatagramPacket ( getdata, getdata.length);
    skt.receive(replyth);
    String arrayth = new String(replyth.getData());
    int threadnr=Integer.parseInt(arrayth.trim());          //convert thread string to int and trim it (whitespace)
    System.out.println("Thread received " + threadnr);

    //length send request
    String lg = "length";
    senddata = lg.getBytes();
    DatagramPacket requestlg = new DatagramPacket(senddata, senddata.length, host, serverSocket);
    skt.send(requestlg);

    //length get reply
    DatagramPacket replylg = new DatagramPacket ( getdata, getdata.length);
    skt.receive(replylg);
    String arraylg = new String(replyth.getData());
    int lengthnr=Integer.parseInt(arraylg.trim());          //convert thread string to int and trim it (whitespace)
    System.out.println("Length received " + lengthnr);


    skt.close();
```

And all i get is something like this:
Thread received 3
Length received 1

(Length should be between 5 and 25 and in my case its never bigger then 5)

Answer (score 0):

The code parses the response from the first message instead of from the last, so you get the random 1-5. I suggest using better names for the variables and you'll spot the problem quicker.